Raspbian carla client -- cannot find working Python version
I  would like to install the Python carla client module for Raspbian. The module exists, but I cannot find a Python version which is capable of installing it.
earlier versions - the same error as 3.5.9
$ pip3.5 install carla
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement carla (from versions: )

$ pip3.6 install carla
source/libcarla/libcarla.cpp:7:10: fatal error: carla/Memory.h: No such file or directory

$ pip3.7 install carla
source/libcarla/libcarla.cpp:7:10: fatal error: carla/Memory.h: No such file or directory$ 

$ pip3.8 install carla
File "<string>", line 31, in get_libcarla_extensions
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'dist'

later versions - the same error as 3.8.1

See the docs https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start_quickstart/ AFAIU pip install carla installs Python wrapper for CARLA (written in C++); you need to install the very CARLA to use its Python wrapper.
